# GCP pubsub pull from a third API REST

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe

I have an API that's from a third party (for me and for gcp), I want to know if it is possible to set a pull that get data from the API into PUBSUB, or from a wrapper API that I can set in my environment.

Basic schema:

(third party API) -Pull-> PUBSUB -Cloud Function-> BigQuery

Comment: Cloud Scheduler -> PubSub topic -> Cloud Function which pull from the external API and save into BigQuery

Comment: Pull or publish?

Comment: Thanks with the Scheduler I can solve my problem because I was creating a Wrapper API, and can make a requerst to my wrapper in order to push the information.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the code of the third party api, you can use the `Google Pub Sub client`, pull the messages and acknowledge them if there is no error.

The Cloud Pub/Sub client libraries use streaming pull to receive messages instead of pull.

The link for Pub Sub Python client for example :

https://googleapis.dev/python/pubsub/latest/pubsub/subscriber/index.html#pulling-a-subscription-asynchronously

You can also check this topic : [How to pull messages from a subscription with GCP Pub/Sub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67800775/how-to-pull-messages-from-a-subscription-with-gcp-pub-sub)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a cloud function, either scheduled via Cloud Scheduler or HTTP-triggered, that pulls the data and publishes to PubSub.  Your next Cloud Function can then be PubSub triggered to move the data from your PubSub message to BigQuery.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).